# PDF that renders in Chrome but not in Acrobat

Tags: pdf

```
%PDF-1.7
4 0 obj
<</Type/ObjStm/N 3/First 14/Length 139>>
stream
1 0 2 41 3 76 <</Type/Catalog/Version/1.7/Pages 2 0 R>><</Type/Pages/Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>><</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 200 200]/Parent 2 0 R>>
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
    /Root 1 0 R
    /ID[<7F1FE2C507E6DB4CB0787E660F2B0C65><2450E4E8FF5FC84380428886C0DD4C2F>]
    /Size 6
    /Index[1 5]
    /W[1 4 1]
    /Type/XRef
    /Length 68
    /Filter[/ASCIIHexDecode]
>>
stream
020000000400
020000000401
020000000402
010000000A00
01000000E500
endstream
endobj
startxref
229
%%EOF
```

The PDF above opens in Chrome (or Edge), but in Adobe Acrobat (Reader) it crashes. Ghostscript regards it as fine too. Note that it assumes CRLF for line breaks.

I read the parts of the PDF spec that are relevant for a basic PDF, and it seems that the above syntax follows it. Why doesn't Adobe like it?

[Here is a link](http://venus.tandola.com/349f7.pdf) to the PDF. Notice how it opens in Chrome, but crashes in Adobe Acrobat. (This PDF uses LF for line breaks, and has a `Resources` dictionary on the page, based on the comments.)

Comment: Please post PDFs (also) as binary downloads, not (only) as text dumps.

Comment: @mkl Added a link to the binary.

Comment: I'm not about to count offsets, but I can tell you that your file is missing a "Resources" dictionary. This is required either at the "Page" level, or in case of using inheritance at the "Pages" level. Whether this is why Acrobat is refusing your file I have no idea.

Comment: Additionally the cross references do not have entries for 0..Size-1 but merely 1..Size-1. But adding an empty **Resources** dictionary and adding a 0 entry still don't make Adobe accept the file.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I tried adding an empty Resources dictionary, and updating the offsets, but it didn't help. Lmk if you'd like the PDF with it in.

Comment: @mkl I updated my link to include a Resources dictionary. I added a bounty. `Cross-reference streams` don't need an object 0, that is only required for a `Cross-reference table`, but thanks for trying these points.

Comment: *"Cross-reference streams don't need an object 0, that is only required for a Cross-reference table,"* - are you sure about that? The pdf specification is not as precise as one wants it to be. In particular Adobe products follow their own interpretations (from the pre-ISO-specification times)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acrobat has the following 2 quirks, both of which do not follow the specs:

1. If the XRef Stream has a single filter, an array must not be used. So `/Filter[/FlateDecode]` won't work, and `/Filter/FlateDecode` will. This may apply to any Stream Object, not sure.
2. An XRef Stream must use the `FlateDecode` filter. `ASCIIHexDecode` won't work. A predictor is not required.

[Here is a link](http://venus.tandola.com/v3n94.pdf) to the above PDF, fixed up for Acrobat.